# EF6 Code First HasForiengKey renames columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first

I have a .net/database project where records are uniquely identified by a version id and a numerical key (taken from a SEQUENCE).
I use EF code first (in fact, code only, because the database must not be modified by code) with POCOs and relations. All relations are specified through modelBuilder actions.

I have a POCO containing (among others) the rows

```
    public long HistoryVersion { get; set; } // version
    public long Id { get; set; } // my unique id per version
    public long OrgUnitId { get; set; } // if of other entity
    public virtual OrgUnit OrgUnit { get; set; } // reference to other entity
```

The reference to the OrgUnit table is by HistoryVersion and OrgUnitId, which are the columns for the primary key in the destination table.
To specify the relation, I use

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Assessment>()
            .HasRequired(me => me.OrgUnit)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(me => new {me.HistoryVersion, me.OrgUnitId});
```

If I try to get the assessment including the orgUnit, I get an SQL error:

```
Invalid column name 'OrgUnit_HistoryVersion'.
Invalid column name 'OrgUnit_Id'.
```

Why does EF create these spooky column names and how can I avoid that (it should take the existing HistoryVersion and OrgUnitId columns)?

Comment: These look like generated by EF6 default convention. One reason could be if you have unmapped inverse collection navigation property. Search your model (and derived classes in the same assembly if any) for public `ICollection<Assesment>` or similar property.